# Are these ideas about the equality of two sets correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have some questions about the equality of two sets. I want to make sure I am understanding it correctly, can anyone verify if these ideas are correct?

1. $A=B\Longleftrightarrow(x\in A\Leftrightarrow x\in B).$
2. $A=B\Longleftrightarrow (A\subseteq B) \land (B\subseteq A).$
3. $A=B\Longrightarrow \vert A\vert=\vert B\vert\,$ but $\vert A\vert= \vert B\vert  \Longrightarrow\!\!\!\!\!\!\!/\,\,\,\, A=B.$ For example $\vert\{1\}\vert=\vert\{2\}\vert$ but $\{1\}\neq \{2\}.$
4. $A\subseteq B \Longrightarrow\!\!\!\!\!\!\!/\,\,\,\, A=B$. Since $A \subseteq B\Longrightarrow (A\subset B)\lor (A=B)$, there could be cases where $A \subset B$ but $A \neq B$. For instance, let $A=\{a\}, B=\{a,b\}$, we have $A \subset B$ but $A \neq B$.

Comment: Can anyone fix not implies symbol? Don't know why its not compiling >:( I tried looking for it in tutorial provided by this website.

Comment: In principle \not\Longrightarrow should work, but the spacing is all messed up (at least for me it is).  You may have to use a silly hack like \Longrightarrow\!\!\!\!\!\!\!/\,\,\,\,

Comment: ...on the other hand, any big objection to using words?: "$|A|=|B|$ does not imply $A=B$".

Comment: @David No objections this is how I keep my notes after, but I understand it can become a bad habit writing maths.

Comment: Regarding the subject matter, all of these statements are accurate and correct.

Comment: @JonathanHebert You can make this as an answer if you like. Im actually gonna share this page to some of my friends aswell and I just need verification. I'm gonna pass it along. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the statements you wrote are accurate and correct.

Regarding presentation, my only nit-picks might be that your $ \forall x$ in 1. is slightly superfluous. You could also change your implication in 4. to a biconditional, but it's not wrong not to.